# Persistence for a python (cherrypy) web application?

Tags: python, web-applications, persistence, cherrypy

I am trying rewrite a simple Rails application I made a while ago with cherrypy and Python3.  So far I have been unable to find a Python replacement for ActiveRecord (the persistence part of the application).  Most of the recommendations I've found on StackOverflow have been for SQL Alchemy.  I looked into this and it seems much too complicated to get up and running.  After reading its online docs and a book from Amazon, It's still not clear how to even proceed; not a good sign.

So my question is, what are developers using to persist data in their python3 web applications?

Also, I looked into Django but python3 is a requirement so that's out.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good luck. At the Web Dev Summit at PyCon this past week, the room full of Python web framework *authors* was asked how many were deploying Python 3 web apps. Zero hands went up. You might want to revisit the Python 3 requirement and wait on it for a couple of years.

SQLAlchemy is a fine choice, however. You might also experiment with NoSQL solutions like Mongo (see http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymongo3 for example).

Comment: Interesting point re the python3 thing.  I mostly wnated to use it because I hate how 2 does unicode.  I'll look into Django again perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Alchemy is a industrial standard is no choice. But it's not as difficult as it seems at first sight

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a transparent persistent storage system for python this is currently in an alpha-stage.  Once you create a persistent object, you can access and modify its attributes using standard python syntax (obj.x=3;) and the persistence is done behind the scenes (by overloading the setattr methods, etc.).  Contact me if you are interested in learning more. -Stefan